# How can I determine the quality of a connection in iOS?

Tags: ios

I'm familiar with using Reachability to determine the type of internet connection (if any) being used on an iOS device. Unfortunately that's not a decent indicator of connection quality. Wifi with low signal strength is pretty sketchy and 3G with anything less than 3 bars is a disaster (not to mention networks that only allow EDGE connections).

How can I determine the quality of my connection so I can help my users decide if they should be downloading larger files on their current connection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A pragmatic approach would be to download one moderately large-sized file hosted on a reliable, worldwide CDN, at the start of your application. You know the filesize beforehand, you just have to measure the time it takes, make a simple computation and then you've got your estimate of the quality of the connection.

For example, jQuery UI source code, unminified, gzipped weighs roughly 90kB. Downloading it from http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.js takes 327ms here on my Mac. So one can assume I have at least a decent connection that can handle approximately 300kB/s (and in fact, it can handle much more).

The trick is to find the good balance between the original file size and the latency of the network, as the full download speed is never reached on a small file like this. On the other hand, downloading 1MB right after launching your application will surely penalize most of your users, even if it will allow you to measure more precisely the speed of the connection.

Comment: While this measures the speed, it doesn't really measure quality. A 50Mb/s connection with a lot of packet loss might be fine for downloading a file thanks to TCP's insurance, but a VoIP connection over UDP would suffer from dips, crackles pops and artefacts. Speed != quality.

Comment: The OP stated that users “should be downloading larger files”, so I assumed he doesn't deal with realtime protocols.

Comment: I was just making the distinction clear, not saying your answer was incorrect or unhelpful. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: No problem, you were right to state this. Not everybody's aware of the difference.

Answer (score 7):

Cyrille's answer is a good pragmatic answer, but is not really in the end a great solution in the *mobile* context for these reasons:

- It involves doing a test "at the start of your application" by which I assume he means when your app launches.  But your app may execute for a long while, may go background and then back into the foreground, and all the while the user is changing network contexts with changes in underlying network performance - so that initial test result may bear no relationship to the "current" performance of the network connection.
- For the reason he rightly points out, that it is "penalizing" your user by making them download a test file over what may already be constrained network conditions.

You also suggest in your original post that you want your user to *decide* if they should download based on information you present to them.  But I would suggest that this is not a good way to approach interacting with mobile users - that you should not be asking them to make complicated decisions.  If absolutely necessary, only ask if they want to download the file if you think it may present a problem, but keep it that simple - "Do you want to download XYZ file (100 MB)?"  I personally would even avoid even that.

Instead of downloading a test file, the better solution is to **monitor and adapt**.  Measure the performance of the connection as you go along, keep track of the "freshness" of that information you have about how well the connection is performing, and only present your user with a decision to make if based on the on-going performance of the connection it seems necessary.

EDIT: For example, if you determine a patience threshold that in your opinion represents tolerable download performance, keep track of each download that the user does in order to determine if that threshold is being reached.  That way, instead of clogging up the users connection with test downloads, you're using the real world activity as the determining factor for "quality of the connection", which is ultimately about the end-user experience of the quality of the connection.  If you decide to provide the user with the ability to cancel downloads, then you have an excellent "input" about the user's actual patience threshold, and can adapt your functionality to that situation, by subsequently giving them the choice before they start the download.  If you've flipped into this type of "confirmation" mode, but then find that files are starting to download faster, you could dynamically exit the confirmation mode.

Comment: There's no answer here, it's just a collection of mobile best practices.

Comment: The answer is "monitor and adapt" because the quality of mobile connections is transient.  Determining the quality of a network connection is sufficiently complex under any circumstances, but attempting to do so on a mobile device under shifting conditions, and then truly relevant choices to the user, is not practical.  If that were not the case, iOS would wrap it up and give it to us as a simple value beyond what reachability gives us.  Will edit the answer to say more about what I mean by monitor and adapt.

Comment: The question is "how do I monitor?"

Comment: Let me know if my Edit to the question explains my view or if you want me to suggest in more detail.

Comment: It's true that there's no single *answer* here. But this is not the kind of question that has a single answer. It's a complicated problem that merit a discussion, not a single prescription. @Rob Reuss has provided an excellent discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Rob's answer is very good, but for a more specific implementation start with (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/SimplePing/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000716)[Apple's Simple Ping example source code](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/SimplePing/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000716)

Target the domain for the server that you want to monitor connection quality to. Use the ping library to "ping" it on a regular basis (say 1 or 10 seconds depending upon your UI needs). Measure how long it takes to get a response to your ping (or if it never returns) to develop an estimate of the connection quality to communicate to your user.