# iOS how to estimate network quality programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, uiwebview

I'm testing my iPad app with a UIWebView using "Network Link Conditioner" developer tool. I have preset it to provide 28.8 kBps speed, and it is really slow, the user is staring at a white screen for a good minute before the URL request times out.

Is there a way to programmatically access the quality of bandwidth or network performance? I know how to use `Reachability`, and ask if if I'm on Wifi or 3G, but is there a way to estimate the true performance of Wifi or 3G programmatically on iPhone/iPad? In other words, how can I know that I'm on a "very bad network"?

[image]

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419382/how-can-i-determine-the-quality-of-a-connection-in-ios